# How to return char* array in c/c++ function?

Tags: c++, c

Following is my function prototype(we can't change the prototype of this function):

```
char** myfun()
{
  // implementation
}
```

How can I return the array of  char* from this function so that I can access/print the content of array in the caller of this method. I tried creating an array using dynamic memory allocation,but it is not working.

Is it possible to do this without dynamic memory allocation.
Could please provide me the pointer?

Comment: Can you show the code where you tried doing this with dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: "I tried creating an array using dynamic memory allocation,but it is not working" - Weird, I don't see any attempt at... anything.

Comment: Be specific C or C++?

Comment: You can dynamically allocate with `char** p = new char*[n];`, then set each pointer `p[i] = new char[k];` and copy the text in (hint - you probably want a terminating `NUL`, make sure `k` includes space for it).  "without dynamic memory allocation" - yes, you could use `static`/global variables, but then you'd have to know an upper limit to the number of strings you'd need to return and it wouldn't be thread safe... not often a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a global char*[] you want to return from this function, yes, you need dynamic allocation, it is the only way you can safely return a variable created inside the function, for all variables stored in the stack will be destroyed as soon as the function finishes.

```
char** myfun()
{
     char **p = new char*[10];
     return p;
     //or return new char*[10];
}

int main() {

    char **pp = test();

    char *p = "aaa";

    pp[0] = p;

    delete[] pp; //if you allocate memory inside the array, you will have to explicitly free it:
                 //Example: pp[1] = new char("aaa"); would require delete p[1]; 

}
```

--Edit

You don't HAVE TO use dynamic allocation, you could return a local static variable. Keep in mind that this is not a good approach though: the function would not be thread safe or reentrant.

Comment: It's not the only way, but as mentioned in the comments, the only safe way is typically not a great idea.

Comment: You are right, you could return a pointer to a static local.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::string> myfun() {
    return {"hello", "vector", "of", "strings"};
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    auto v_of_s = myfun();
    for (auto &s : v_of_s) {
        cout << s << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f43c86db9b196340)

Or, in old C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> myfun() {
    std::vector<std::string> v_of_s;
    v_of_s.push_back("hello");
    v_of_s.push_back("vector");
    v_of_s.push_back("of");
    v_of_s.push_back("strings");
    return v_of_s;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    vector<string> v_of_s = myfun();
    copy(v_of_s.begin(), v_of_s.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa096acfd72f255b)

Comment: `auto &s` - why a mutable reference?

Comment: @MSalters just to avoid type `const`.

Comment: `auto s` is even shorter.

Comment: @MSalters but that produces a string copy unnecessarily.

Comment: @MSalters If I could, I would employ [next generation for loops](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/01/n3853)